# React text state doesnt update immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

i am trying to update the text and show the month, the calander updates but the month doesnt update untill i click the next month button twice, but if i click the next month button twice the month is also changed twice in the calander and it shows the previous month on the header.

This is The March month

[image]

This is April Month but the month shown is March.

[image]

this is my Code

```js
const [showmonth, setShowMonth] = useState(moment().format("MMMM-YYYY"));
const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState(moment());

const increaseMonth = () => {
    setDateValue(moment(dateValue).add(1, "M"));
    onDateChange(dateValue);
  };
   function onDateChange(value) {
    setShowMonth(value.format("MMMM-YYYY"));
  }
```

```html
<RightOutlined
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "23px",
                    fontWeight: "700",
                    cursor: "pointer",
                  }}
                  onClick={increaseMonth}
                />
```

Please Help i am a beginner

Comment: You are using the old state here: `onDateChange(dateValue);` this is what causes your observed behavior. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: yeah i got my answer, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making separate states for your date object and the current month, why not just keep the dateValue as the only state and get the month from that.

```
const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState(moment());

const increaseMonth = () => {
    setDateValue(moment(dateValue).add(1, "M"));
};
```

Then, you can have the value of your month be

```
dateValue.format("MMMM-YYYY")
```

This has less code and you only have to update the date object and then your month will update when the days update.

Comment: ThankYou so Much that worked and helped me optimize my code.

Comment: Glad it worked!